# How to remove single numbers from string whilst preserving the order

Tags: python, string, duplicates

```
def pos_and_neg(a):
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    return [ x for x in a if not (x in seen or seen_add(x))] 

print pos_and_neg([1,2,3,-1,-3])
```

This needs to return

```
[1,3,-1,-3]
```

Comment: You mean you only want to keep a value if it is present in both positive and negative (e.g. 1 and -1, 3 and -3)? What if there are repeats?

Comment: yes exactly, make it modular to any print you through at it

Comment: There are no strings involved here...

Comment: list *** sorry, instead of string

Answer (score 0):

```
 def pos_and_neg(a):
    return [ x for x in a if (x*(-1)) in a] 
 print pos_and_neg([1, 4, 6, -1, -4, -6, 5, 7, -7])
```

output:-`[1, 4, 6, -1, -4, -6, 7, -7]`

Comment: sounds good but will it work for lets say print pos_and_neg([1,4,5,6,-1,-4,-6]) im just trying to make it modular so it can work on any print you throw at it

Comment: @NickBergeron for `[1,4,5,6,-1,-4,-6]` it has output:-
`[1, 4, 6, -1, -4, -6]`

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
def pos_and_neg(l):
    unique = set(l)  # use a set for faster lookups
    return [i for i in l if (i*-1) in unique]

>>> pos_and_neg([1,4,5,6,-1,2,-4,-6])
[1, 4, 6, -1, -4, -6]
```

Though it will not handle duplicates, so if you had `[1,1,-1]` all values would be kept, instead of removing one of the `1`s.